# Change the default comments in GIT's COMMIT_EDITMSG after typing "git commit"

Tags: vim, git, vimrc

Sometimes when I'm at work, I want to commit and push changes to my own projects on GitHub. So I do a lot of `git config user.email` to make sure that I don't *commit* with my email at the company and that I in fact use my own personal email. Now I have `export GIT_EDITOR=vim` in my `~/.zshrc` file, so that every time I type `git commit`, vim opens up and I see a file like this:

```py
my actual commit message
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch master
# Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#         modified:    vim/.vimrc
#
```

Is there a way that I can modify these comments? So that it shows something like this:

```py
my actual commit message
# Email: me@my.site
#
# On branch master
# Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#         modified:    vim/.vimrc
#
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `prepare-commit-msg` hook to insert comments or other text into the commit message.  I don't know if the default message is in the file at the point the hook is run, but even if not, you can insert additional commented text into the commit message at this time.

Note that the hook can be invoked in several ways, and you may or may not want to modify the commit message in all of them.  Regardless, you can see the configuration of the hook and the argument it takes by running `man githooks`.

Note that if you want to use this set of hooks globally, you can use `core.hooksPath` in your `~/.gitconfig` to set a global hook directory.

Answer (score 0):

if it is just about a commit message you can easily use

```
git commit --amend


git commit --amend -m "commit_message"
```

it is for most recent commit

also use `git log` for see your commits

> if you push your commits in github and your project commit is private you cant change it in free version

you just have to make a new commit in this kind of situations

Comment: It's not about the git message, I wish to change the default comments in `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file.

Answer (score 0):

> It's not about the git message, I wish to change the default comments in `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file.

@AmirShabani You can do this with `git config commit.template`… See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt-committemplate.